# C# - Correct way to set up CancellationTokens for highly concurrent methods

Tags: c#, task

I have a function that refreshes the UI every time an object raises an event. However, any single object can raise multiple events within 1 sec, and there could be 10,000+ objects in the collection doing this. My idea is to capture the very last event and discard any pending ones after 1 sec intervals.

The following `RefreshCollection()` function is called every time any object raises any event.

```
SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreUpdatingList = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreRefreshingView = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
CancellationTokenSource _ctsRefreshView = null;

internal void RefreshCollection()
{
    // if we're in the process of changing the collection, return
    if (_semaphoreUpdatingList.CurrentCount == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (_ctsRefreshView != null)
    {
        _ctsRefreshView.Cancel();
    }
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (_ctsRefreshView == null)
        {
            _ctsRefreshView = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }
        var ct = _ctsRefreshView.Token;
        try
        {
            await _semaphoreRefreshingView.WaitAsync(ct);
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(() =>
            {
                CollectionView.Refresh();
            });
            stopWatch.Stop();

            // Only refresh every 1 sec
            if (stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000 - (int)stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
            _semaphoreRefreshingView.Release();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            _ctsRefreshView = null;
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, very rarely I am getting a `_ctsRefreshView is null` error inside the task when I'm calling this `var ct = _ctsRefreshView.Token;`. I am scratching my head as to why this is happening.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: The one thing that is boggling my mind is: Why are you not just instantiating the `_ctsRefreshView` token source outside that scope? Why are you doing that lazy instantiation?

Comment: Also, you aren't `await`ing your `Task.Run()`. That could cause some weird behavior if you run this method back-to-back where one task hasn't finished, but another started.

Comment: @Andy I thought that would be the correct way since I am also nullifying the token inside the Task.

Comment: What else are you doing here, is `CollectionView.Refresh()` the entire point of this method? or are you doing other IO or cpu work?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes, only `CollectionView.Refresh()`. No IO or CPU work.

Comment: Maybe capture the cts as a variable within the scope of the task, then access the token, then set the `_ctsRefreshView` field with that variable. That might avoid any race condition you're having between the time you instantiate the cts and the time you access it

Comment: This looks like a perfect job for RX Debouncing / Throttling, it could be done in a few lines of code... paging @Enigmativity

Comment: @MichaelRandall - Absolutely. That's exactly what I'm thinking.

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thanks for the suggestion. I am very new to concurrent programming and really trying to learn the basics before I start using libraries.

Comment: @MichaelRandall - I've put forward a solution. It's super simple.

Comment: Also you don’t need a StopWatch - just start the Delay task before your Refresh action and await it afterwards - this way the task starts first and the await afterwards guarantees that if 1s isn’t up yet it will wait the only remaining time. I.e. `var throttleTask = Task.Delay(1000); Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(…); await throttleTask;` would do the same your current Stopwatch code does with less clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Threading` (for WPF bits) and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

And if you had a `collection` this class:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public event EventHandler Ping;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>> query =
    collection
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(x =>
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
                    h => x.Ping += h,
                    h => x.Ping -= h))
        .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1))
        .ObserveOnDispatcher();
        
IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(x => CollectionView.Refresh());
```

That will give you at most one call to `CollectionView.Refresh()` every `0.1` seconds.

That's much easier than mucking around with cancellation token sources.

And just call `subscription.Dispose();` to stop it all.